# Add radio input dynamically to jQuery Mobile fieldset controlgroup

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I've seen variations on this question but not my specific case on SO, so here goes.

I'm having trouble adding a new radio input dynamically to an existing control group using jQuery Mobile. It will add, but the style is not correct and it doesn't appear to interact with the other inputs correctly.

Here's my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjindustries/3mQF6/

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Or is is a case of regenerating the whole fieldset /controlgroup again? :(

Thanks! Code below too...

```
        <div id="testPage" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Radio buttons, vertical controlgroup:</legend>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked">
            <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2">
            <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3">
            <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>
            <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4">
            <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
    </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>

$('<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-5" id="radio-choice-5"><label for="radio-choice-5">Horse</label>')
    .appendTo("fieldset");

$("fieldset").trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `name="radio-choice-1"` as you have used in above. This solves you behavior problem

Behavior problem solved with below change
Your modified code for dynamically adding radio.

```
 $('<input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-5"><label for="radio-choice-5">Horse</label>').appendTo("fieldset");
```

Style problem solved with below change
Just recreate div instead of fieldset

```
 $("div").trigger('create');
```

Check [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/zdsGu/)

Comment: Doh! I was so busy looking for a jQM problem that I neglected basic HTML! Thanks :)